# Realtime date time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to check the time elapsed from now. For example `5 minutes ago` like that. I want to make it live without any page refresh. Is `date-fns` package is suitable for this? and how to do so, Can I watch for the changes with a `Watcher` in `Vue JS`. Thanks if anyone can help me with this situation.

`formatDistance` method in date-fns is suitable for this?

Comment: try moment.js https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you are using the composition API.

You can use the [`useTimeAgo` composable from VueUse](https://vueuse.org/core/usetimeago/). It returns a formatted string in the format you described, updating with a specified interval.

Example:

```
import { useTimeAgo } from '@vueuse/core'

const theEvent = new Date(2022, 0, 1)

// The time can be a Date, string, or number, or a `ref` holding one of those.
// Whatever you give, the value is passed through `Date`.
const timeAgo = useTimeAgo(theEvent, { updateInterval: 30_000 }) // Update every half minute
```

You cannot specify `requestAnimationFrame` as the interval, unlike with the underlying `useNow` composable, but this shouldn't ever be needed. [Antfu's response when I asked](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/issues/2072#issuecomment-1210992689):

> `useTimeAgo` only needs very low accuracy of the time, using `requestAnimationFrame` would be too costly and would increase the bundle size.

See also: [`useNow` on VueUse](https://vueuse.org/core/usenow/).

Comment: Really helpful if you explain more about requestAnimationFrame with an example with useTimeAgo

Comment: I'm afraid that, while actually supported as an interval by the `useNow` composable used by `useTimeAgo`, `useTimeAgo` does not allow specifying `requestAnimationFrame` as an update interval.

Comment: I've updated my answer and opened an [issue about it on the VueUse repo](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/issues/2072)

Comment: Updated to include info from Antfu